# Push and delete or Reroute? Blue Green Deployment on CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, blue-green-deployment

**Is there a reason that the [CloudFoundry documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html) recommends the following steps for Blue-Green deployment (we're in Pivotal CloudFoundry):**

1. Push GoodApp_new
2. Add GoodApp route to GoodApp_new (load balancing between them)
3. Remove GoodApp route from GoodApp
4. Remove GoodApp_new route from GoodApp_new
5. Delete GoodApp
6. Commonplace followup step: Rename the GoodApp_new to GoodApp

**When the following steps seem equivalent?**

1. Rename GoodApp to GoodApp_old (routes remain unchanged)
2. Push the new version with the name GoodApp (effectively load balanced, has correct routes by default because the app name is correct)
3. Delete GoodApp_old

Maybe its uncommon that all the correct routes are added during the push?

Maybe there is an unforeseen side affect to renaming the app [that isn't in the documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/managing-services.html#rename_service)? Our APM setup already handles having multiple app names floating around for the few seconds that that will be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with either approach.  There are a handful of ways to do blue/green deployment, so you can pick the one that works best for you and your workflow.

That said, I would suggest using an existing and tested plugin for the cf cli, instead of rolling it yourself.  It's not a super complicated process but there are a handful of plugins so if one fits your workload you may as well use it.  It'll save you a little time and it's vetted by the community.

Plugin list here -> https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/

The one that I see used a lot is https://github.com/contraband/autopilot, but that isn't a knock against any of the other plugins.

Hope that helps!

Comment: One gotcha I ran into: Environment variables configured after the push ARE NOT preserved when using the manual steps or the [blue-green-deploy](https://github.com/bluemixgaragelondon/cf-blue-green-deploy) plugin. I'm not sure about other plugins, but you may need to roll your own if you configure environment variables manually (outside of a config server, properties file or manifest).

Comment: [Antifreeze](https://github.com/odlp/antifreeze) is a solution for this issue. It's recommended in the readme for the Autopilot plugin linked in the answer (which does not preserve env vars either).